# Recorriendo respuesta de la API

Tags: php, html, json, curl

Tengo la respuesta de una API con cURL

```
$response       = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$Respuesta      = json_decode($response);
$message            = $Respuesta->message;
if ($message == "COMPLETADO") {
  $datos            = $Respuesta->datos;
  $objeto       = json_encode($datos, true);
  //print_r($datos);
}
```

Al imprimir, me muestra:

```
[{
"Code":1,
"description":"Factura de prueba",
"name":"CASA MATRIZ",
"city":"Ciudad1"
},{
"Code":2,
"description":"Factura de prueba2",
"name":"SUCURSAL 1",
"city":"Ciudad2"
}]
```

Ahora, quiero mostrar esos resultados en un tabla
Cuento los datos en la respuesta.

```
$count          = count($datos);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  echo'
  <tr>
    <td>'.$datos['Code'].'</td>
    <td>'.$datos['description'].'</td>
    <td>'.$datos['name'].'</td>
   <td>'.$datos['city'].'</td>
  </tr>';
}
```

pero, me da error, alguien me podria ayudar por favor?

Comment: ¿Lo que pones debajo de: *Al imprimir, me muestra:* a qué corresponde exactamente, a `print_r($datos);`? Pon `var_dump` en vez de `print_r` para ver de qué tipo es eso, pues no se adivina desde el contexto, o mejor aún, muéstranos el resultado de `var_dump($Respuesta);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí ya estás convirtiendo tu respuesta a objeto:

```
$Respuesta = json_decode($response);
```

Entonces, no marees más los datos haciendo más conversiones, simplemente usa la parte de la respuesta que necesitas, que al parecer es lo que hay en la propiedad `datos` de `$Respuesta`.

**NÓTESE** que para obtener los valores en los `td` se usa la notación `$objeto->propiedad` y no `$array['key']` porque lo que hay en `$Respuesta->datos` es un array de objetos. También, al poner todo el `echo` dentro de comillas dobles, evitas las concatenaciones con el `.`

Así debería funcionar:

```
$response       = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$Respuesta  = json_decode($response);
$message    = $Respuesta->message;
if ($message == "COMPLETADO") {
    foreach($Respuesta->datos as $datos){
      echo"
          <tr>
            <td>$datos->Code</td>
            <td>$datos->description</td>
            <td>$datos->name</td>
            <td>$datos->city</td>
          </tr>";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Diria que el problema que tiene tu respuesta es que `$Respuesta->datos` sigue en formato **json**, si es que el `print_r($datos);` que aparece comentado se corresponde con lo que dice que se le muestra al imprimir

Comment: @masterguru pero no es un *problema*, simplemente, me estoy quedando en el contexto inicial. Aquí: `$Respuesta = json_decode($response);` se convirtieron los datos a objeto, por tanto, no tiene ningún sentido voooolver a hacer otra conversión, mareando los datos. En `$Respuesta->datos` ya habrá un array de objetos y se puede leer ese array de objetos sin necesidad de más reconversiones.

Comment: Es lo que no tengo por seguro, si realmente en $Respuesta->datos hay un array de PHP o aun de json por los motivos que sea, de ahi mi duda acerca de tu respuesta... esperemos al OP que nos lo aclare a ver.. mi respuesta se basa en que el print_r($datos) se corresponde con lo que aparece después, pero podrías tener razón, claro.

Comment: @masterguru observa estas dos líneas en el código de la pregunta: `$datos            = $Respuesta->datos; $objeto = json_encode($datos, true);` Parecería que OP intenta convertir a un array asociativo el array de objetos que ya tiene en `$Respuesta->datos` sin ninguna necesidad. Luego se ve un `print_r($datos);` que no ayuda a identificar el tipo, por eso lo pedí que usara `var_dump`, pero lo lógico es que si creó un objeto, lo que haya en `$Respuesta->datos`  sea un array de objetos. OP puede trabajar con ese array de objetos sin volver a convertirlo en array asociativo pasando `true`.

Comment: jeje, no si claro que entiendo tu punto de vista... pero yo sigo con mis trece y mi lógica basándome en la premisa del print_r($datos) que pienso que veo alli... a ver si despierta el OP y nos lo aclara de una vez :-)

Comment: A ver lo que nos dice Op :-) Yo, en ningún caso, haría un `json_decode` para luego, hacer `json_encode`, es a eso que yo llamo *marear los datos*, convertirlos y reconvertirlos... meterlos en un envase y agitarlos y sacarlos de ese envase, meterlos en otro y agitarlos... sin necesidad ninguna. Un código así no estaría optimizado.

Comment: mmm... creo que al final tendrás razon y lo que está imprimiendo con print_r es el $objeto y no los $datos (aunque aparezca comentada esa linea)... yo es que habia descartado mirar lo que hacia con $objeto porque luego el for era con $datos, pero si, ahora me parece más lógico lo tuyo... jolin!! que rabia! porque no hacen bien las preguntas??? xD

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchisimas gracias.
Aun me cuesta entender la diferencia con los objetos.

Comment: @A.Cedano pos vaya, dada esta respuesta del OP veo que tenias razon, lo que se veia despues al imprimir era el $objeto y no los $datos, a pesar que se habia dejado un **// print_r($datos)** por ahi para confundirme y hacerme quedar mal supongo :-)  Ale, respuesta eliminada, premisa equivocada y ahora hago como los avestruces y escondo la cabeza bajo tierra, je

Comment: @JuanTorres, es muy simple. Si pasas `true` como segundo parámetro a `json_decode` vas a obtener un array, y la forma de leer los arrays es `$array['key']`, si no pasas nada o pasas `false`, obtendrás un objeto, y la forma de leer los objetos es `$objeto->propiedad`. Está todo explicado en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php). En cuanto a la depuración, para conocer el tipo de dato, la longitud de los valores, etc, es mejor usar siempre `var_dump` en vez de `print_r`.

Comment: @masterguru no eres el único al que le ha pasado. Tu respuesta podía ser válida también, sólo que los datos volvían a convertirse, lo cual no es óptimo para este caso.